AWS Classifier column updates not reflecting in catalog
Have an classifier (.csv) having 6 columns. Source system sends data without header, recently the source has has swapped the column position of phone & address. In classifier have updated the change as well.
For example:
before update (version 1): "name", "age", "email", "phone", "address", "pincode"
after update (version 2): "name", "age", "email", "address", "phone",  "pincode"
Post change ran the crawler again but the columns order is as per version 1 which is causing incorrect columns ?
